# How to add external library using spring boot with embedded server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8, external-dependencies

I would like to know if is possible use external jars with web application that uses spring boot with embedded server.

Example:

```
java -cp external.api -jar app.war -spring.config.location=application.properties
```

When I use application I got errors like ClassNotFoundException for classes that are inside of external jar.

Comment: Why aren't these external jars in the runtime dependencies of your app?

Comment: you mean, inside of lib folder? if yes, there is a requirement that this library musn't be encapsulated into project due to infrastructure upgrades.